# Regex us number format with specific format for +1-xxx-xxx-xxxx?

Tags: javascript

this is my code but doesn't work and i dunno why?:

```
const phoneRegex = RegExp(
  /^\(\+1\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})$/
);
```

that solution came from this, which works for xxx-xxx-xxx:

```
const phoneRegex = RegExp(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})$/);
```

how do i add +1- from the beginning to make +1-xxx-xxx-xxxx work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the  you're trying to match '(' and ')' literally in the (+1) portion, the `'\'` means you want to escape the character. If you meant that to just be an optional capturing group, update it to: `/^(\+1)?[-]?([0-9]{3})\)?[-]?([0-9]{3})[-]?([0-9]{4})$/`

Comment: hey i don't want it optional :(

Comment: If you want all parts required, exclude the ? from each group:  /^(\+1)[-]([0-9]{3})\)[-]([0-9]{3})[-]([0-9]{4})$/ https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html has some good tutorials on regular expressions.